# restore UIImageView Image in IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am adding an image in `IBAction`, I want to restore the old image back once the button is tapped.

It is not the image in the `UIButton`, it's the image in the `UIImageView`

```
- (IBAction)findMe:(id)sender
{
   [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]];
}
```

I want to restore`@"image1".` immediate once button is tapped
some thing i need is some thing similar to

```
button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

but i don't want to change Button Image, but change UIImageView Image when clicked

Comment: Do you want to toggle? Default it has image1 then on first you tapped on button then it should be image2 and then on second tap it should be back to image1

Comment: not toggle change back immediate some thing similar to selected highlight

Comment: Please explain what you want.

Comment: We are doing this for button image [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted]; What i should do if i have different UIIMageView but not ButtonImage

Comment: Are you saying when you began touching a UIButton then UIImage in view will change and when you released the tap from same UIButton then UIImage in view will change back to what was before.

Comment: Man you should have explained right way I just figured out. No Problem I will just post the solution

Comment: Did you try my answer? My answer will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touch2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touch3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now the selectors

```
-(void)touch2:(UIButton *)send
{
    imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
}

-(void)touch3:(UIButton *)send
{
     imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];
}
```

Comment: I like your answer. I guess way to solve this problem may by subclassing the UIButton. using onTouchBegan and onTouchEnded method.

Comment: You don't need `.png` in the image names if you use `imageNamed:`.

Comment: Thanks. I have not checked it with images but i think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out:

```
- (IBAction)findMe:(id)sender
{
   if (self.imageView.image) {
      // store your old image here
      NSLog(@"%@", self.imageView.image)  
   }
   [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]];
}
```

Comment: no i need some thing similar to highlight image. just change image when button is pressed and go back to 1st image after tapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first create gesture for UIButton

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *btn_LongPress_gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleBtnLongPressgesture:)];
    [buttonFindMe addGestureRecognizer:btn_LongPress_gesture];

When you press and release the button it calls this method.

-(void)handleBtnLongPressgesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

```
//as you hold the button this would fire

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    //Change your image 1
}

//as you release the button this would fire

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    //Change your image 2
}
```

}